# Phonegap ajax request not connecting on iOS device

Tags: javascript, ios, ajax, cordova

I'm trying to send a jquery ajax request to a server in Phonegap for iOS, but something is going wrong. Using the $.ajax function, neither the success or error callbacks are firing. I have the server url whitelisted. It works fine if I run the application in a browser, either on my laptop or on mobile safari, but nothing happens when it is run in the simulator or on a device. This is was working a few hours ago. The only thing I can think of that I changed is I added a new build configuration for ad hoc distribution, but I don't see how that could have done anything.